# binding to remote IP

Tags: networking

I have two servers and would like one server to be able to use some of the other's external IPs. Server A has 20 IPs and server B has 5 so I want B to use 5 of A's IPs.

How would I go about this? Would I need to create 5 openvpn tunnels from A to B?
My goal is for server B to have 10 distinct outgoing IPs.

Comment: Are these two servers on the same network? Also, is there one particular type of traffic you want to redirect, or all traffic?

Comment: Also, what kind of answer are you looking for? Do you just want an overview of what your options are, or do you need detailed configuration instructions?

Comment: I hate when I have to ask this question but what are you actually trying to do? There's probably an easier way to accomplish it than this.

Comment: Why not just reassign 5 of the IPs from A to B?

Comment: @derobert They are not on the same network. Basically I'd like to be able to do things like 'wget --bind-address=x http://etc.' . Detailed instructions would be cool, but right now I don't even know if it is possible or what my options are.

Comment: @JoelDavis One of the things I'm doing, is querying remote web servers for which I need a pool of external IPs so as not to get blocked too easily. Server A has a bunch of IPs I'm not using and I'd like to put some of them to use.

Comment: @cjm Both servers are not on the same network and are not hosted by the same ISP so unfortunately that is not an option.

Comment: What kind of queries are you running on these web servers? Especially if you're worried about making it harder to block you. You might try just setting up a web proxy on the remote server and just occasionally routing your requests through that so that it looks like the requests are coming from the other node.

Comment: I will also say that the fact that you're worried about someone block you is kind of fishy. Sounds a little....illegal possibly.

Comment: The queries I'm running are simple shell/php scripts that retrieve website pages from a variety of sources. Things like searching through online trademark databases, etc... Believe me, nothing illegal is going on. Just want to stay below radar and spread out my requests over a number of IPs.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here are your options, broadly speaking. I suppose you can research and then ask followup questions as needed. For this discussion, A has the IP addresses that you'd like to use on B.

### NAT

Traffic is routed to A. A then does both SNAT and DNAT. Unfortunately, this really only works for *incoming* connections. It sounds like you want outbound. You can make this work, though, by doing DNAT on B (to send the connection to A) then SNAT and DNAT on A to send the connection from the right IP.

For incoming traffic to one service, this is far the one of the two easiest approaches, the other being a proxy. For outgoing traffic, it sounds much more convoluted than it is—its a few `iptables` commands.

### Distribute the Workload

Generate your outgoing connections from A. Send the generated data back to B. This of course takes work to set up, but it is the most scalable solution. Once you've done the work, you can add servers C, D, E, etc. as needed.

### Proxies

You could set up a HTTP or SOCKS proxy on A. Then connect to it from B. The proxy can be configured to distribute load amongst the multiple IPs on A.

OpenSSH's port forwarding is basically the same idea. You can dynamically change the port forwards over an existing connection, but I'm not sure at what rate—OpenSSH may not work for your outbound application.

### Tunnels

There are a bunch of ways to do tunnels. The basic ones to look at are the unencrypted tunnels like IPIP and GRE and the encrypted ones like OpenVPN and IPsec ESP.

Basically, they all work like this: You set up a virtual link between your two servers. Then you use the normal kernel routing machinery to direct the traffic over the link, just as you would were it an Ethernet cable or serial line. You can send as many addresses over one link as you'd like.

Note that unless you can get reverse-path filtering turned off, you will have to do policy routing to make sure your outgoing packets go over the link, instead of directly to your default gateway.

Many tunnels have the downside of reducing the MTU. You should be able to compensate by reducing the TCP MSS. Alternatively, you can not reduce the MTU, at the cost of a lot of fragmentation.

Building a tunnel will let you have the IPs as local IPs on B; same with the leased line below. The other methods don't.

### Lease a private line

Included only for completeness, as surely buying more IPs on server B would be cheaper, but you could lease a T1 (etc.) between the servers. Then you can route your traffic over it.

### Don't Be Evil

Having read the rest of the comments on the question, the primary way to not be blocked is not to be abusive. Keep your request rate as low as possible, respect `robots.txt`, etc.

Comment: Let's look further into the tunnels, as my first attempt at tackling this involved tunnels. Earlier today I successfully created an unencrypted virtual link using openvpn but got stuck configuring both servers, using iptables, route, etc... How would I direct traffic from B to A, from A to the WWW and then back to B?

Comment: @Martin if you want to go the tunnel route again (I think I'd try a proxy first) you can ask questions about the particular problems you were/are facing. You do all that directing with `ip route` (and I guess `ip rule` as well).

Comment: What I did was:
`ip route add default via 10.0.0.2 dev tun0 table vpn_table
ip rule add from 10.0.0.1/32 table vpn_table
ip rule add to 10.0.0.2/32 table vpn_table
ip route flush cache`

And on the other server the same but with IP addresses swapped. Ping worked on both servers, but `wget --bind-address=10.0.0.2 website` didn't on server B

Comment: @Martin that's not quite right. Only B uses `ip rule`. A just uses routing. You also need to make sure to enable IP forwarding on the box. I suggest starting a new question with details—let this one remain as the "in general, what are my options question". Hard to properly answer questions in comments.